# Combining while loops for CLI tools

Tags: python, while-loop, command-line-interface

Is there a clean way to combine while-true loops for getting user input in CLI tools? I need 3 inputs for 3 distinct questions, which have to be immediately validated as well. Right now I'm just putting in in three while loops and that works fine, but it feels a bit off.

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("Enter a:")
    if validate(a):
        break
    else:
        continue

while True:
    b = raw_input("Enter b:")
    if validate(b):
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes of course that's what functions are for:

```
def get_input(prompt, validate=validate)
    while True:
        res = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            res = validate(res):
            return res
        except ValidationError as e:
            print("invalid value: {}".format(e))
```

Note that I changed the `validate` API so that it's now supposed to raise a `ValidationError` instead of returning a boolean. This allow to have an error message explaining what's wrong... Also it returns the validated value, which allows to typecast it if needed (if for example you want an int or float) or to actually return whatever you want as the final result.

Answer (score 1):

```
def validate_input(q):
  res = None
  while not res:
    res = validate(raw_input(q))
  return res

a = validate_input('Enter a')
b = validate_input('Enter b')
```

Answer (score 1):

This program firstly ask the the three questions, validates them and then asks in loop only for questions that didn't validate. Until all questions are validated:

```
# This is only example validate function:
def validate(resp):
    if resp == "a":
        return True
    return False

valid = [False, False, False]
while not all(valid):
    a = valid[0] or input("Enter a:")
    b = valid[1] or input("Enter b:")
    c = valid[2] or input("Enter c:")

    valid = [True if valid[i] else bool(validate(v)) for i, v in enumerate((a, b, c))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the questions you might step through the questions in a single loop, something like:

```
questions=["1+2?","3+4?","5+6?"]
answers=["3","7","11"]
idx=0
while idx<3:
  if answers[idx]==input(questions[idx]):
    idx=idx+1
print("Okay")
```

However if validation involves separate, different procedures, [Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263548/7916438) is more manageable.